# Simple update query fails with MySQL

Tags: php, html, sql

I have tried practically everything but I cannot get this simple update query to work.

Array shows:

```
Array ( [pSelect] => 102 [budget] => 44 [submit] => submit )
```

So I can conclude that it does get the ID and receives the value from the input field `budget`.

```
  <form action="test.php" method="post" action="test.php">
  <select name = 'pSelect' id = 'pSelect'>       
  <?php
 $result = mysql_query
("SELECT ID, Project, Projectnummer, Klant, Budget
  FROM tblproject
  WHERE Status = '1'
  ORDER BY Klant ASC
");
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $pID = $row1['ID'];
    echo "<option value=\"" . $row1['ID'] . "\"";
    if (isset($_POST['pSelect']) &&  $row1['ID'] == $_POST['pSelect']) 
    { 
    echo " selected='selected'"; 
    } 
    echo ">" . $row1['Klant'] ." ". $row1['Project'] ." ". $row1['Projectnummer'] . "</option>";
        echo "<br />";
}
?>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="budget" />

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $ID = $_POST['pSelect'];
    $budget = $_POST['budget'];
    mysql_query 
    ("  UPDATE tblproject SET Budget = '$budget',WHERE ID = '$ID'");
}
print_r($_POST);
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a comma after `Budget = '$budget',`

Comment: also no need for double action in form tag

Comment: My gosh it works, spent so many hours cuzz of that lousy comma!!! =| tnx guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by Steven, you have an errant comma at the end of `Budget = '$budget',`

And please, please, please... if you're not going to use Prepared Statements/Parameterised Queries could you at least use the mysql_real_escape_string() function on all the parameters to your queries? e.g.:

```
$query = sprintf("
    UPDATE tblproject SET
    Budget = '%s'
    WHERE ID = '%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($budget),
    mysql_real_escape_string($ID));
    );
mysql_query($query);
```

The alternative is somebody causing SQL Injection problems in your application at some point.

Comment: Tnx, selected as best answer, i use real_escape_string but this piece of code is prototype, part of a larger system.

I think the program is a total of 3000 lines php, bummer i spent a whole day because of a comma, hahaha i feel embaressed.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tblproject SET Budget = '".$budget."' WHERE ID = '".$ID."' ");
```

Comment: i ussualy do that but was out of options, problem solved cant click on steven to solve this thread and i cant answer myself... ?? this is very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UPDATE tblproject SET Budget = '".$budget."'   WHERE ID = '".$ID."'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `UPDATE` query:

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE tblproject SET Budget = '".$budget."' WHERE ID = '".$ID."'");
```